# Docker put_archive error docker.errors.NotFound:

Tags: python, api, docker, copy

File not found error with Docker put_archive. I am using the Python API for Docker. 
Docker version 1.12.5, build 7392c3b

```
docker.errors.NotFound: 404 Client Error: Not Found ("lstat /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/39d58e00519ba4171815ee4444f3c43d2c6a7e285102747398f6788e39ee0e87/var/lib/neo4j/certificates: no such file or directory")
```

I am unable to copy files to a created docker container.

```
con = cli.create_container(...)
cli.put_archive(...)
cli.start(con['Id'])
```

If I change the order of operation there is no error and the files are copied exactly to where I want them. So I know my code is working and doing what I want it to do. But it's important to copy configuration files to a container before it is started. Copying the files after the start causes the container to start with a default configuration and not the custom configuration which needs to be copied into place before the container is started. Docker claims that this issue is closed but it is still affecting my application.

This works; Same code different execution order.

```
con = cli.create_container(...)
cli.start(con['Id'])
cli.put_archive(...)
```

Comment: Weird. I think that should work. Maybe try to replicate this using `docker create` and `docker start` in the terminal could shed some light on this?

Comment: fails consistently from a terminal (python interactive).  After starting the container;  the file handle listed in the 404 error is valid.  The code used to  copy files works perfectly after starting the container but not on a "created" container.  This is such a critical feature for containers that need config files before starting.

Comment: I mean using the docker comman directly.

Comment: fails from command line

Comment: # docker inspect neo4j-test | grep State
            "Status": "created",

# docker cp ../dev/nginx/ssl/fhcrc.pem.crt neo4j-test:/var/lib/neo4j/certificates/neo4j.cert
Error response from daemon: lstat /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/024bd08880ccce02cd6b9cae2e36f5465b76d5ca4914b17045bc1ac0f0576e9e/var/lib/neo4j/certificates: no such file or directory
# docker start neo4j-test
neo4j-test
# docker cp ../dev/nginx/ssl/fhcrc.pem.crt neo4j-test:/var/lib/neo4j/certificates/neo4j.cert